# Which dissimilarity index to use with categorical ecological data

Tags: r, categorical-data, biostatistics, ecology, vegan

I am currently working on data representing the abundance of microorganisms in a categorical way, like 0 = no organisms; 1 = 1-5 organisms; 2 = 6-10 and so on (5 being the highest number). And i am not quite sure which dissimilarity index is best to use with vegdist for that kind of data, to then do Pcoa etc. So i wanted to ask if someone has any experience and could recommend an index?

Thanks in advance!

[image: For reference, that what the data is looking like:]

Comment: Is there a reason you are categorizing them this way in the first place?

Comment: Yes, i get the data from wastewater treatment plants and they categorize it that way, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have an ordinal variable. This is sometimes used for plant species but also some microorganisms. I'd first inform R that those columns are an ordinal factor:

```
factor(myData$free_bacteria, ..., ordered=TRUE)
```

Then, I'd use some form of model-based unconstrained ordination method to come up with an ordination diagram, which would give you the same result as PCoA.

This is because none of the dissimilarity coefficients available in `vegan::vegdist` can handle ordinal variables.

On the other hand, `gllvm` can to that by using `gllvm(data, ..., family="ordinal")`.

The package `ecoCopula` also has an ordinal family.

Answer (score 0):

Your scaling is like any class scale that are in common use. For instance, vegetation people in Germany use analogical Braun-Blanquet scale. You can use any dissimilarity index of your choice.